# How do I transfer exactly as many credits as I want to a factory in X: Beyond the Frontier?

Tags: x-beyond-the-frontier

In [X: Beyond the Frontier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X:_Beyond_the_Frontier) (note: the original, not [X-Tension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X:_Beyond_the_Frontier#X-Tension)) the player has to provide an initial amount of credits for each factory that they acquire, so that it will be able to buy the resources that it needs.

That is accomplished via the trading screen, where the player transfers credits from their ship to their factory. The player uses the left and right arrow keys to transfer credits back and forth. The problem is that the amount of money transferred with each key press seems to be dependent on the amount of money present on the ship.

As a result, when you have a lot of money (e.g. 1,500,000) the "step" increases accordingly. Is there a way to transfer funds in a more fine-grained way?